# What browsers do CouchDB support?

Tags: browser, couchdb

What browsers/versions do CouchDB support?
I googled but did not find the result.
I want to know that does CouchDB support below browser/platform and from which version?

Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Internet Explorer, Opera? 
Android ?
iOS ?
Windows Phone ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by browser support for database server?

Comment: So, you rather want to know about the [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/). That is why you had trouble searching for PouchDB-specific feature using CouchDB keyword :) This is different system, which was inspired by CouchDB and meant to be CouchDB compatible. Couch works strictly on server, Pouch is implemented in JavaScript and may run in browser. According to its [home page](http://pouchdb.com/), it supports Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE and Node.js.

Comment: perhaps this question is ambiguous, my purpose is to use an offline database in html5 mobile app, such as indexedDB, pouchDB. I am not sure whether CouchDB is a in-browser database? Can I use it as the offline local database in html5 mobile app?

Comment: I want to use CouchDB itselft, not PouchDB. But how can CouchDB be used in all mobile platform, such android, ios... Is there a so-called couch.js to support this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

None. CouchDB will not run itself in the browser. It hasn't be designed for this.

However can be easily accessed from a browser because its API is HTTP-based.

[PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com) is a very popular choice for CouchDB users who wants something that runs in the browser. PouchDB can be used as a **client for a CouchDB database** running on a server, as an **in-browser database**, or even **both** with very little additional work using its powerful replication mechanism.